# About lambert W function`s solution

Tags: lambert-w

I like to know solution of  below equation.
$$e^{-0.0042x}(1+0.0042x)=0.032$$

I use 'WolframAlpha' and get two real solution(x=-235.259 and 1256.97).

General solution is $x=-\frac{5000}{21}(W_{n}(-\frac{4}{125e})+1)$ (n is integer)

I naively know when n=0 lambert w function give me a real value.

But when i set n=0, the answer is -235.259 but what i like to get is 1256.97.

Which value of n can give me 1256.97?

Thank you!

Comment: $n=-1$ is the other branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most reference material of the Lambert W function will tell you that the two branches of the multi-valued function are referred to as $W_0$ and $W_{-1}$.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)